# The integral of a simple function $\psi$ defined on a set of infinite measure.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

According to definition pg. 71 in Royden 4th edition :

The integral of a simple function $\psi$ defined on a set of finite measure $E$ by:

> [image]

But I can see that this definition is also applicable for an infinite set $E$ as can be seen in this solution:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Does Royden not define the integral of a simple function on a set of infinite measure? Besides, you have not picked the solution out of Royden, so there may be differences in the ways in which the solution reference and Royden approach the subject.

Comment: I do not think that Royden defined the integration of a simple function on a set of infinite measure...... may be I am incorrect .... please tell me on which page in Royden if it is defined on it ...... the problem is from Royden page 85 #26 ..... so I am assuming that the solution used a previous knowledge from pages before 85 ..... ultimately my goal is to understand why this definition is correct for infinite sets ...... so if you help me in understanding this , I will be very grateful to you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Oh the question is from Royden? I will check Royden and get back.

Comment: Yes, in Royden there is the section "integral of a non-negative function" where the integral of a function $f$ is the supremum of the integral of all finitely supported $h \leq f$, then for such $h$ the definition is via simpe functions, which will all then have finite support. The question you mention is in the exercises of this section, so Royden and his solution do not miss anything.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  so how can I precisely justify this last step in the solution ..... does every simple function has finite support and bounded ?

Comment: Yes, I think the $f_n$ are not simple, but can be approximated by simple functions very obviously, so the definition of Lebesgue measure applies here. That is a error in the given answer, but a small one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: You cannot define the integral of  the simple function $I_{(-\infty,0)} -I_{(0,\infty)}$ on the whole real line becasue $\infty -\infty$ is not defined.

However the integral of a non-negative simple function over any measurable set can be defined. For example the intergal of $I_{(0,\infty)}$ over the real line can be defined as the limit of the integral over $(-n,n)$ and we do not encounter $\infty -\infty$ here.

Comment: So why the definition is correct in our case in the solution? or is it incorrect?

Comment: @Secretly I hope the explanation I have given now clears your doubts.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  so how can I precisely justify this last step in the solution ..... does every simple function has finite support and bounded ?